# Trigger Gradle Task after import Eclipse Project

Tags: eclipse, gradle, build-process, buildship

We ported our custom Gradle setup (GWT, builder configuration etc.) for Eclipse from the STS Gradle Plugin to the Buildship Plugin.

We use special self-developed tasks which are performed automatically after an import of a Gradle project through the STS plugin via the eclipse-task and afterEclipseImport-task. Does the new Buildship plugin allow to trigger tasks after the import in Eclipse in a similar manner?

Has anyone of you successfully triggered a Gradle task after project import with the Gradle Buildship plugin?

Comment: did you manage to resolve this? I am trying to trigger an xjc execution after an eclipse import as well

Comment: No, nur you can do this with The spring gradle plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never: It has been introduced in Buildship 3.1 and requires Gradle 5.4 or above:
https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2019/june/buildship.php

You can register tasks to be executed every time Eclipse is synchronizing the workspace with the working copy:

```
eclipse {
    synchronizationTasks myCustomSyncTask
}
```

And tasks to be executed every time Eclipse is performing a build:

```
eclipse {
    autoBuildTasks myCustomBuildTask
}
```